# In Kafka, how can we transactionally, consume from a topic X and publish to a topic Y. So if publish to Y fails then my consumer offset is unchanged

Tags: transactions, apache-kafka

I have a usecase where I must consume from a topic and publish to another topic. I anything fails then effectively nothing should change in these topics.

Answer (score 1):

From Kafka 0.11, you can use transactions to obtain such behaviour. 
Kafka comes with an example that precisely does that, it consumes messages from a partition and produces them to another partition using transactions.

Apart from doing regular transaction logic, all is needed is to reset the consumer position to the last committed offset if a transaction fails and only commit offsets when transactions are successful.

For the complete logic, see https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/tools/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/tools/TransactionalMessageCopier.java